# How can I sort array of numbers higher to lower (reverse/decreasing order)?

Tags: android

How can I sort array by numbers higher to lower.

*Array*

```
ArrayList<TestClass> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

*Class*

```
public class TestClass{

   public boolean type;
   public int counter;

   public TestClass(boolean type, int counter) {
       this.type = type;
       this.counter = counter;
   }
}
```

*I tried do this*

```
Collections.sort(array1);
```

*But I got error*

> reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that TestClass conforms to Comparable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any accessory methods, you can use

```
array1.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.counter));
```

The sorting order you asked for is reverse order, there are couple of ways to achieve this.

You can simple do a reverse of the previous sort like

```
array1.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.counter));
array1.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

If you can't user `Comparator.comparing`, you can do as follows

```
Collections.sort(array1, (item1, item2) -> Integer.compare(item2.counter, item1.counter));
```

The above statement can be explained as below.

- `Collections.sort()` is provided from `Java collections framework`.
- First argument specifies which collection needs to be sorted.
- Second argument depicts on how each object in the collection should
  be evaluated with other object in comparison. So for every pair of objects, in your case integers here, the condition returns true if the second element is greater than the first one. Which will pull the entire list to appear from higher to lower

Comment: `Comparator.comparing` working with 24 API and higher but my app support 19 API and higher

Comment: @AAA checkout my updated answer. Does any of them work for you?

Comment: You can't use `Compartor.comparing`?

Comment: `Compartor.comparing` It's working with 24 API and higher but what about 19 to 23 API ?

Comment: @AAA How about my current implementation using `Collections.sort` ?

Comment: `array1.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.counter));` this line It's working but the problem It's support 24 API and higher

Comment: @AAA this should work for your situation `Collections.sort(array1, (item1, item2) -> Integer.compare(item2.counter, item1.counter));`

Comment: It's working now but I can't understand this well `Collections.sort(array1, (item1, item2) -> Integer.compare(item2.counter, item1.counter));`

Comment: We are using the `Collections.sort` method from Java collections. The first parameter specifies which collection to sort and the second parameter specifies on which condition it should be sorted

Comment: I can't understand second parameter but I'll try know it by myself. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with some explanation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayList.sort(new Comparator<TestClass>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TestClass testClass, TestClass t1) {
            return Integer.compare(t1.counter, testClass.counter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not working for me , I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure you used correct parameters, because if don't use, the list will be sorted in increasing order.